# decimal format for big numbers in java

Tags: java, decimalformat

While using the DecimalFormat object to format numbers in Java, I noticed that the largest number it can support is "1,000,000,000", so I tried to multiply it by 10 like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###.##########");

System.out.println(df.format(1000000000*10));
```

And this is what I got:

```
1,410,065,408
```

I didn't understand this result, shouldn't it be 1E10 ?

Does anyone of you guys knows how to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the `DecimalFormat`, but with your integers.

When you do `1000000000*10`, it goes out of range for `int` type and results in `1410065408`.

You will need to perform the operation with `long` numbers instead.

```
System.out.println(df.format(1000000000l*10)); // Notice the l for long.
```

You will then see proper results.